# Installing ubuntu inorder to Install boot loader

Tags: usb

I deleted my Partition for Ubuntu and my Windows OS cant load.
How can I load Ubuntu into a USB so I can install the boot loader on my PC ?

Comment: @Parto user293996 may have difficulties with the *create a live USB-stick in Windows* parts in your link because he said his Windows OS can't load.

Comment: @karel In that case, he would have to either repair the windows OS first or use another computer to create the bootable USB.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have deleted your Ubuntu installation, the best bet would be to use your Windows installation disc and start the installation. And when the installer starts, instead of installing Windows, go to "Repair your computer". In the next page, if it finds your Windows installation, uncheck it before clicking Next. Then click on "Command prompt" and run these commands.

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

For more details visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader and in particular https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader#Windows_Vista_or_7_or_8

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "windows boot loader" from your windows installation disk to be able to run your windows. If you don't have a disk you can search online for some programs that can install windows boot loader for you but you have to burn the program on a disk of course.

Ubuntu installs "grub". grub won't let you run windows, it lets you go to windows boot loader so that you can run windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to reinstall Ubuntu. It will detect your Windows at the installation and proceed with a side by side installation.

That process will rewrite the summary of your Hard disk and install grub. You will then be able to boot on Windows by restarting your computer.

To manage the grub menu, I can recommend you to install Grub Customizer on Ubuntu (making a search on the internet will lead you to the ppa to install). Once you got it simply run the soft, manage your parameters as you want and then clic "save".

I recommend to keep a small free partition to install Ubuntu in case of malfunction of your Hard Drive. Proceed with that kind of installation can help you rearranging your disk.